# How to select which disks are allowed to sleep?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, sleep-wake, power-management

There is an option "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" in Mac OS X's preferences:

[image]

Is it possible to configure which disks Mac OS X can put into a sleepy state? For example, I want to leave only the drives which are installed in my laptop, but not the drives that are connected via USB. How can I reach this?

Comment: Why not the USB drives?

Comment: @duci9y my external 2.5" USB hard-drive cannot wake up (doesn't start spinning) after Mac OS X puts it into sleep.

Comment: That's probably an isolated issue, as my external drives wake up, AFAIK. Hope someone is able to help you.

Comment: System starts working veeery slow, Finder doesn't open at all after Mac OS sent the external harddrive to sleep. The only solution is to unsafely eject a USB-cable from MacBook.

Comment: It is too hard for me to find the reason of this issue.So it would be much easier to configure which disks the system can put into sleep.